# SumIf based on current month in column

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have this table:

```
|       1       |       2       |       3       |       4       |       5       |       6       |
|------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| A | B | C | D | E | F | G | H | I | J | K | L | M | N | N | O | P | Q | R | S | T | U | V | W | X | Y
|------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| n | n | n | n | n | n | n | n | n | n | n | n | n | n | n | n | n | n | n | n | n | n | n | n | n | n
| n | n | n | n | n | n | n | n | n | n | n | n | n | n | n | n | n | n | n | n | n | n | n | n | n | n
| n | n | n | n | n | n | n | n | n | n | n | n | n | n | n | n | n | n | n | n | n | n | n | n | n | n
| n | n | n | n | n | n | n | n | n | n | n | n | n | n | n | n | n | n | n | n | n | n | n | n | n | n
```

where number 1-6 (but it actualy goes futher up to 12) stands for month and where "n" stands for random number.
What do I need is to add colum at the end and in each row count data from current row and up to todays month (A, E, I, M, P, T, X,...) but based on current month, so if currentmonth is 4 (by today), then sumup "n" cols (A, E, I and M), if would be only february then sumup only cells in this single row by  current month (so sumup only A and E).

simple in VbA, however I need it as excel formula.

Have no idea how do I even start

Comment: Assuming the first row is merged, you can use SUMIFS.

Comment: What version of Excel?  Will you always be ignoring columns `B,C,D,F,G,H,...`? Are the two  `N`'s in Row 2 under 4 a typo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given your data layout, if you have the latest version of Excel, with the `SEQUENCE` function, you can use:

```
=SUM(INDEX(3:3, SEQUENCE(MONTH(TODAY()),,0,1)*4+1))
```

If you don't have the `SEQUENCE` function, try:

```
=SUM(INDEX(3:3,N(IF(1,(ROW(INDEX($A:$A,1,1):INDEX($A:$A,MONTH(TODAY()),1))-1)*4+1))))
```

*With the latter formula, especially, you may need to "confirm" this **array-formula** by holding down <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> while hitting <kbd>enter</kbd>.  If you do this correctly, Excel will place braces `{...}` around the formula as observed in the formula bar*

Comment: Hello, sam as comment in previous answer, no matter what I do It works for first column in each month only, for second column I have no luck modifying to make it work, can you please show how?

Comment: @JiriZaloudek Without knowing what you did, it's not possible to know where you went wrong. I put the formula in some cell, and then filled down for the number of rows. Got one result for each row.

Comment: yea that works fine, but how you do it for other columns?

Comment: @JiriZaloudek You need to understand how the formula works.  The columns argument is generating an array where each element represents a column.  If you want to look at the 2nd column for each month, just add `2` instead of `1`.

Comment: Yes, works awesome! Marking as best solution... on the other hand if I would want to make it as perfection, how would i skip showing 0 and return only ""? Same way as IfError(calculation,"") but for "0" returns?

Comment: One easy way is to just use a custom format on those cells.  That way, the contents would still be zero, but it would show as  a blank. Or wrap the formula in an `IF` to test for it.

Answer (score 0):

You say it's simple in VBA, but you need a formula.
When you declare a VBA function as public in your module (`Public Function Calculate_Month(...) as ...`), you can use that function as a formula:

```
=Calculate_Month(...)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `SUMPRODUCT` function:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((A3:X3)*($A$1:$X$1<=MONTH(TODAY()))*($A$1:$X$1<>""))
```

[image]

Comment: THis works fine, however I see in column V you have sum for yellow fields, how do you make new column "W" and make sum of all column next to yellows? (B, F, J,...)